# Methods for dynamically selecting the modules of a library in C

Tags: c, module, dependencies, c-preprocessor

I am looking for some information on patterns commonly used to configure a library in C.

I want to introduce some concepts of the library so I can bring some context to the problem.  The library is for embedded systems so careful consideration has been used (and some tricky not so pretty methods) to keep the library light and feature-rich.

The library is made up of modules that for the most part, are designed to be as decoupled as possible. Some cross dependencies are required, some are optional (this is an important note). What I mean by that is, some modules become more advanced when other modules exist, but instead of forcing the user to include modules they don't need (keep footprint small) the advanced features could be left out. A good example of this is the following. The UART module has a UART_Tick method that needs to be called to handle the processing of incoming data and errors periodically. Instead of requiring the user to always worry about that, if the task (a simple scheduler) module is included in the project, then the UART module schedules the task itself and the user no longer has to call the UART_Tick function. However, to keep things light, the task is ONLY scheduled if the Task module is used.

Now let me explain how I've gotten away with things like this so far and why I don't like it.

Every project has a system.h file. Here is what system.h provides

1. Module configuration. Example:

   ```
   #define UART1_BAUD 115200
   ```

   This configures the UART 1 Channel to have a baud rate of 115200. Pretty simple
2. Project dependencies Example:

   ```
   #include "library.h"
   #include "uart.h"
   #include "system.h"
   ```

Briefly, this was done this way because it allows the user to specify what modules they need, and it allows the modules to use the system.h file to find configuration macros and also find out what other modules are used so that it can dynamically change itself.

Now, here is what I don't like about it:

1. The library can't be built separate from the project. For my use
   this is sort of fine. But it would be awesome to actually be able to use make and cross-toolchain build tools to simply build the library and link to it.
2. The preprocessing including is a mess. There are mutual includes that don't even make sense to me at this point because everything is including system.h to get info. I know this is bad.
3. It's confusing for the user of the library
4. It doesn't really solve all the problems with the module cross-dependency without causing issues.

The only other solution I can thing to use is global pre-processor defines. But I don't really think that solves the problem completely either. And they are usually gruesome to configure and easy to forget.

I know I may not find the perfect solution, but I would appreciate any experience/thoughts/viewpoints to maybe spark a better solution than the one I have.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: you can use the dlopen / dlsym / dlerror / dlclose functions to dynamically open shared libraries and access the functions in the libraries.

Comment: @luserdroog when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: One approach might be to build lots of tiny libraries and select modules at link (or run) time. You'd still have to compile your library for each target _system_, but then the user can pick and choose the modules they want without recompiling by just linking against the parts they care about.